# Text Labels on Google Maps v3 showing as text under marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am using v3 on Google Maps and there has been no code change from my site. Today I saw, the functionality was maybe changed, or what, by Google.

I am using something like this:

```
var m = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(b[0], b[1]),
    map: map,
    icon: img,
    label: " <strong>" + b[4] + "</strong><br />Autor: <strong>" + b[5] + "</strong><br />Dĺžka: <strong>" + b[6].replace('.', ',') + " km</strong>"
});
```

It looks like:

[image]

When I hover over the marker, its like:

[image]

This is ok, but in both cases there is also shown text from `marker.label`, which couple days ago was not showing like this. Its the same text, as is shown in the bubble, when the marker is hovered.

I also tried as I was searching for an hour on SO to change the `marker.label` to object:

```
var m = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(b[0], b[1]),
    map: map,
    icon: img,
    label: { text: " <strong>" + b[4] + "</strong><br />Autor: <strong>" + b[5] + "</strong><br />Dĺžka: <strong>" + b[6].replace('.', ',') + " km</strong>" }
});
```

But the text over map is still shown, and then in the bubble is showing only `[object Object]`.

**Question**

Does anybody know what could be the problem here, or what google changed in their v3 API?

Its not possible to paste so huge code to JSFiddle, hope you understand. The website is [www.cyklomapy.sk](http://www.cyklomapy.sk).

Any help from anyone who has faced similar issues will be very appreciated.

Comment: My question is not about, why is not my code working... Is about, that its not working on all websites using google maps API v3!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, not (just) a link to a broken website.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Maps Javascript API v3 was modified to remove the restriction on the marker label (used to be only one character allowed).

- [Issue 8578: Remove 1 char restriction for marker labels](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8578)

Comment: And then how to show no text over the marker, and show text only in the bubble?

Comment: My suggestion would be not to put more than one character in the label field of the marker (and certainly no HTML). The code in your question doesn't include the code that displays the "bubble", and I'm not going to search your page to find that, but my guess is that you are using the label property incorrectly in there, and it only worked before because of the limitation.

Comment: The text, which is shown in the bubble is that from the label. And this was not before google changed it. And now, the text is showing also in the bubble, and also in the label. I don't want to show any text in the label, only in the bubble. And so it was working for 2 years till today (or couple days ago). And as I searched many times here on SO, it was also such working, and also you may use HTML and then you will have formatted text in the bubble. Google changed it, not me...

Comment: Issue 8578 is an enhancement request to increase the number of characters available in the marker label from 1 to more than one. It was addressed by Google.  My take is you were using the label field of the marker incorrectly (as it always placed a label on the marker, you just happened to set the first character to a blank).

Comment: Yes, thats true, first character was blank, but in the bubble it was showing formated HTML code from the label. Now there is whole text in the label and no HTML code in the bubble. And my question is, how can I add formatted HTML text to the bubble, not to the label.

Comment: There is no code in your question to show how the "bubble" is being created